# Why is my index page dumping table data at the end of the list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting this output when I got to the /projects, which should just list projects and an associated link:

[image: Projects index]

I cannot figure out why all the information from the projects table is being dumped after the list.

Controller index method:

```
def index
  @projects = Project.all
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= @projects.each do |project| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to project.title, projects_path(project) %>
    <%= link_to project.link, project.link %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas to why this is happening?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Can you share the code of your Project model please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `<%=` on your loop to `<%`:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
```

What it's doing now is executing the loop and printing all your `li` elements, and then also printing the contents of `@projects` (because of the `<%=`).